# How to Schedule a node "Promoted to front page"?

Tags: 7

I am looking for a way to schedule "Promoted To home page" nodes to appear after a particular time.

When user creates a new node and checks "Promoted To home page", it should not appear immediately on publish on the homepage.

Then need a scheduler which set "Promoted To home page" nodes to appear on front page.

The node will published and visible if accessed directly or seen in other section.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed description of the steps the user takes in this scenario. (e.g. Is published checked or unchecked when creating the node?

Comment: @undersound  published can be checked or unchecked at the time of creation as I can make a conditional check in the script to show published checked only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module in combination with the "Rules Scheduler" (a submodule of it). After you enable these 2 modules, create a Rules Component and a Rule. Here is a blueprint of doing so:

- Create a Rules Component which accepts "node" as a parameter, and which has a Rules Action to set the node to "published".
- Create a Rule like so:

  - Rules Event: Before saving a new node.
  - Rules Actions: (1) set the node to "unpublished" (to be sure it is not "published" when the node is saved) and (2) schedule the Rules Component created in the previous step.

**Note**: From the comment below this answer (which states "*The node will remain Published all the time.*") it doesn't seem to apply for the question here, but using a similar approach you could also schedule another Rules Component to mark it unpublished again later on, eg X days after the node gets published. In that case, you use Rules Event "After updating an existing node", combined with a Rules Condition to check if the update changed "unpublished" to "published".

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. The node will remain Published all the time. The only case is to show on homepage after a certain time.